# mould for boring enclosures

Tags: drilling, molding

For an electronics device that I make I use a standard plastic (I think polystyrene) enclosure. This enclosure needs to be precision-drilled, ant I lack the dedicated equipment. What I think would work is to pour some kind of mould on the outside of the enclosure and bore it as needed. I would then reuse the mould for drilling other enclosures.

And to the question - what material and thickness I should aim for for the said mould ?

Comment: The thickness will be based on the strength of the material selected, so a metal mould might be thinner than, say, a wooden one and this could be important when making the mould.

Comment: Why pour the mold and not simply use a wooden board? Is the surface you need to drill complex?

Comment: @mart Already tried making one out of wood / metal sheet. It is too difficult, the enclosure is not a perfectly flat box.

Answer (score 1):

the way this problem is usually solved is to precisely machine a chunk of metal to fill the  inside of the box snugly, and then clamp or bolt that chunk to the drill table. when you start drilling the box wall, the metal core inside it prevents the plastic from flexing. you continue drilling until the bit passes all the way through the plastic wall and engages the metal chunk. Then you withdraw the bit and pull the box off the core.

If you cannot afford to have the core machined from metal, a good substitute is epoxy casting resin. you coat the inside of the box with *mold release*, pour the resin straight into the box and let it harden, then strip the box off and there's your core.

By immersing a bolt into the soft epoxy so its head is in the epoxy and its threaded end sticks up out of it, you then have a convenient means of fastening the core to your drill table after the epoxy hardens.

It is common to blend metal or mineral powder with the epoxy to made it sturdier.